How to quit Mosh inside Tmux inside Mosh
The inner Mosh says:
mosh: Last contact 428:08:30 ago. [To quit: Ctrl-^ .]                                                                               

However, using that key combination will quit the outer Mosh.
I tried to prefix Ctrl-B in some way (the control character of Tmux) but that did not work.
(Maybe related: quit qemu ... inside screen inside tmux)

While playing around further, and also searching online, skimming through mosh issue: ctrl-^ escape not ideal, I realized, I can prefix with another Ctrl-^. Ctrl-^ Ctrl-^ . does not work. But Ctrl-^ ^ . does.
Tmux in between does not matter here. It does not handle the Ctrl-^.
